# Journal Office 365 Doesn't Work

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office, office365, journal

my office have Office 365, for audit reason i need to setup one email account to get all inbound and outbound from all users@xxx.com.

i'm already setup in Admin Exchange Center

1. Compliance management
2. tab Journal Rules
3. add new rule (https://prnt.sc/tm0xxa)
4. set undeliverable journal to (https://prnt.sc/tm0yym)

already wait this rule around a week but i didn't get any email to abc@xxx.com (email account in step no 3)

if any something wrong in my step/configuration?

Thankyou

Comment: Is the journal recipient an Exchange Online mailbox?

Comment: Hello @joeqwerty , first i try using mail account  in domain office 365, second i try using email account outside domain office 365

Answer (score 0):

The internal recipient could receive the journaling reports, but the external recipient couldn't?

If so, please check if the email senders receive a undeliverable message which is about that the recipient(Journaling email address) rejected the message, or if some spam emails went into recipient's **Junk Email** folder?

If there were some undeliverable messages in sender's inbox folder or spam emails in recipients' Junk folder, maybe the recipients added your server domain or sender email address to their block lists or spam filters, so you could try to add your server domain or sender email address in recipients' allow lists and then try to send emails again to check if the journaling reports go into recipients' inbox folders.

Comment: Hi Ivan,  i dont get it for first setence,
but i'm already setup filter/allow my local domain in office 365 and still doesn't work
thankyou

Comment: Based on your description(Try setting internal or external recipient as a journaling recipient), i'm here to confirm the test result of the two scenarios: 1. Could internal recipient receive the journaling reports? 2. Could this specific external email address receive them? 3. If you set external email address in another domain as a journaling recipient, will this external mailbox receive these reports? @Aliga